# Get ID for a lazy many-to-one object with NO db access

Tags: nhibernate

I wonder if this is possible with any Nhibernate version.

I have a class A with a property of class B connected by a lazy many-to-one relation. I'd like to get A.B.Id without going to the database (I mean, without getting the whole B entity).
Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do it! Hibernate is smart enough to not deep-load objects unless you need their other properties, so calling `A.getB().getId()` shouldn't result in the deep-loading of B (it'll use the id of B stored in A).

Here's a website that explains the concept in a bit more detail: [Getting the Id from Lazy Loaded Object Using Annotations in Hibernate](http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/hibernate_lazy_field_access_annotations.shtml)

Try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: I thought this was not the case taking into account what I found searching for this but I tested and it works perfectly. Nice surprise. Thanks!